# JPanel paint() not drawing image at times

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw a graphical depiction of the moon.
For this I am first painting a `JPanel` black and then painting an `Image` to depict the moon on it.
All fine till here.

Next a second `Image` (a mask) is painted on top to simulate the Earth's shadow to get the different phases.
However, at times the mask is painted but at times it is not painted, leading to a full moon being shown incorrectly. <strike>This is happening totally at random!</strike> While `left clicking`, I'm getting this for `mask-01.png`, `mask-06.png`, `mask-12.png`, `mask-17.png`.

A GIF with the individual frames after each `Right click`:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0lWxG68xR4mTlFYYU81N1kzaVE/view?usp=sharing

What am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class App {
    int moonAgeDays = 0;
    float LUNAR_CYCLE_DAYS = 29.5306f;
    JFrame frame;
    MoonImage moonImage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    App window = new App();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    App() {
        frame = new JFrame("Moon Draw");
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        moonImage = new MoonImage();
        moonImage.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                moonAgeDays += mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 ? 1 : -1;
                if (moonAgeDays < 0)
                    moonAgeDays = (int) LUNAR_CYCLE_DAYS;
                else if (moonAgeDays > LUNAR_CYCLE_DAYS)
                    moonAgeDays = 0;
                updateMask();
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(moonImage);

        updateMask();
        frame.pack();
    }

    void updateMask() {
        int phase = (int) Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(-Math.cos(moonAgeDays
                / LUNAR_CYCLE_DAYS * 2 * Math.PI)));
        moonImage.update(phase, moonAgeDays > LUNAR_CYCLE_DAYS / 2 ? 180 : 0);
    }
}

class MoonImage extends JPanel {
    private int phaseAngle = 0;
    private int rotateBy = 0;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int MOON_PADDING = 10;
    private final int MOON_SIZE = 130;
    private final Image IMAGE_MOON = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/moon.png"));
    private final Image IMAGE_MASK[] = {Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-01.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-02.png"))  ,
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-03.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-04.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-05.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-06.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-07.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-08.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-09.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-10.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-11.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-12.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-13.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-14.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-15.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-16.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-17.png")),
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(MoonImage.class.getResource("/resources/mask-18.png"))};

    MoonImage() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(MOON_SIZE + MOON_PADDING * 2, MOON_SIZE + MOON_PADDING * 2));
    }

    /** Update MoonImage with a Mask and Angle to rotate Mask by*/
    public void update(int phaseAngle, int rotateBy) {
        this.phaseAngle = phaseAngle;
        this.rotateBy = rotateBy;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphic) {
        super.paintComponent(graphic);

        boolean resultMaskDraw = false;

        Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) graphic;
        graphics2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics2d.fillRect(0, 0, MOON_SIZE + MOON_PADDING * 2, MOON_SIZE + MOON_PADDING * 2);
        graphics2d.drawImage(IMAGE_MOON, MOON_PADDING, MOON_PADDING, this);
        int phaseBy10 = Math.round(phaseAngle / 10);
        if (phaseBy10 != 0) {
            if (rotateBy != 0) {
                AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
                at.translate(MOON_SIZE / 2 + MOON_PADDING, MOON_SIZE / 2 + MOON_PADDING);
                at.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotateBy));
                at.translate(-MOON_SIZE / 2, -MOON_SIZE / 2);
                resultMaskDraw = graphics2d.drawImage(IMAGE_MASK[phaseBy10 - 1], at, this);

            } else
                resultMaskDraw = graphics2d.drawImage(IMAGE_MASK[phaseBy10 - 1], MOON_PADDING, MOON_PADDING, this);
        }
        String maskInfo = phaseBy10 == 0 ? "No mask" : String.format("mask-%02d.png", phaseBy10);
        graphics2d.setColor(phaseBy10 == 0 || resultMaskDraw ? Color.BLUE : Color.RED);
        graphics2d.drawString((phaseBy10 == 0 || resultMaskDraw ? "Drew: " : "Failed: ")
                + maskInfo, 5, MOON_SIZE + MOON_PADDING * 2 - 5);
    }
}
```

I have tried this in Linux (Kubuntu with OpenJDK) and Windows 7. Same issue in both...

**Note**:

1. System has decent specs, 8GiB of RAM and a 500GiB SSD with enough free space.
2. What is even more surprising is that there is failure in `drawImage()` for almost all the images; you'll see the info text painted in red first then in blue!

Comment: You mixing heavy and light weight components.  Start by using a `JPanel` instead of `Container`. Then override it's `paintComponent` in preference to the `paint` method

Comment: @MadProgrammer Same issue with `JPanel` as `Container` but thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Kanchu - I tried the code and it looks nice! However I could not see the issue you reported. Maybe its an resourcing issue? I ran it in IntelliJ. Some suggestions you may want to try. I noticed you load the image everytime, it might be more performance to  load all the images in memory (array), after all they are static. Also check the runtime parameters to see if memory settings are correctly set

Comment: @Kanchu, sounds clausible but you should confirm this for yourself. Regarding the problem your having, I couldn't reproduce so I am not sure how I can help. Maybe my machine is high-spec.The symtom sounds not to be related to the code so I suggest you look at the environment. Good luck

Comment: @MinhKieu, I have moved to using a `array`. Also, as noted, the system has decent specs with 8GiB of RAM and a 500 GiB with adequate free space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it!

On line `118` it should be:

```
resultMaskDraw = graphics2d.drawImage(IMAGE_MASK[phaseBy10 - 1], at, this);
```

instead of

```
resultMaskDraw = graphics2d.drawImage(IMAGE_MASK[phaseBy10 - 1], at, null);
```

But really strange as the draw fails only at some times and not always!

Comment: when you said "fails" can you describe how does it fail in detailed?

Comment: @MinhKieu, have a look at the GIF or try the code to replicate. Some of the times, `drawImage()` for the `mask` returns `false` which as per Javadocs : `if the Image is still being loaded`, so doesn't get drawn/fails to draw...

Comment: So that may have answered your question. The toolkit is not loading the images on time. I suggest you load all images into memory upfront and see if that resolve your issue.